# Assign zero to specific indices of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indices

For example:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];   
b = [2 4]; %//Indices I got
```

How can I set to zero every element of `a` not indexed in `b` in order to obtain:

```
0 2 0  
4 0 0   
0 0 0
```

I tried `for` loop:

```
for i = 1:numel(a)  
    if i ~= b  
      a(i) = 0;
    end       
end
```

but the matrix I cope with is really large and it takes ridiculously long time to finish running.

Is there any smart way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
b = [2 4]; 

a(setdiff(1:length(a(:)),b)) = 0;
```

**UPDATE**

As proposed by @Daniel, for large matrices is better to use

```
a(setdiff(1:numel(a),b)) = 0;
```

Comment: Use `numel(a)` instead of `length(a(:))`. The later can be very slow for large matrices.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! Thank you @Anton and Daniel. I was doing image processing's stuff. Now the function can run like a charm, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to [Anton's direct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35531027/5067311) is one based on copying:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
b = [2 4]; 

atmp = a(b);
a = zeros(size(a));
a(b) = atmp;         %// copy needed elements
```

I guess efficiency of the two approaches boils down to allocation vs `setdiff`. Also, if your resulting matrix has many zeroes, you should perhaps consider using a `sparse` matrix.